magento 2.4 login page meta title does not get localized
I have a multi store view magento where each store view has its own language but I have an issue with translating some pages.
For regular pages (aka pages that I create via backend in Content > Pages) I can put the translation for meta title in the Search Engine Optimization panel of the page. For other type of content, I can put my translation strings in a csv file.
There are pages, however, that I  don't create via backend, such as the login page. The login page has the meta title "Customer login" set via xml layout. The problem is that I can't find any setting in backend to translate it. Csv translation doesn't seem to work either.
Is there a way to translate the meta title and description for the hard-coded magento cms pages?

CSV translation should work for title.
I have just tried to update en_US.csv and it is working fine

After updating CSV, I can see updates on front as well

For translation you can check another answer Here

As it is rendering from the  tag, which by default does not support translation.
Still, you can override customer_account_login.xml inside your theme or code and explicitly add a title from the XML that supports translation.
Check below example code below for your reference.
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Login</argument>
    </arguments>            
</referenceBlock>

Let me know if it works, Thanks!
